# How to correctly measure the height of a view before it is drawn

Tags: android

So I have extended a view class in order to customize it, and I want to know what height/width it will take up given the context it created when the object is constructed, but before the object is drawn.

I have used the following code but the output from `getMeasuredHeight()` is not the same as when I call the `getHeight()` method after the element has been drawn.

```
    measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `OnPreDrawListener` in `ViewTreeObserver`, remember to return `true` in order to let Layout draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following observer

```
{
ViewTreeObserver treeObserver=measuringView.getViewTreeObserver();
            treeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height=measuringView.getHeight();
        }
        }
}
```